# What happens after a "DROP DATABASE postgres"

Tags: postgresql

I have a funny question about PostgreSQL database: What happens if the `postgres` database is dropped?

`dropdb postgres` worked.
`createdb postgres` worked too.
`psql` worked.

But I thought the users would be lost. Yet the old users are still there.

So where are the users stored for the database and which implications does dropping the `postgres` database have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL metadata are stored in *catalog tables*, which are in the `pg_catalog` schema. These are accessible like regular views and tables.

There are *shared system catalog tables* which are shared between all databases. These tables are not affected when databases are dropped.

`pg_authid`, the table where the users are stored, is one of those shared catalogs. This is because in PostgreSQL, users don't belong to a database, but to the whole database cluster.

You can list all shared catalog tables like this:

```
SELECT relname FROM pg_class
WHERE relisshared AND relkind = 'r';
```

[In the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html) you can find more information about the system catalogs.

Comment: I took the liberty to turn it into a real answer. Rollback if you don't approve.

Answer (score 4):

When connecting to a Postgres server, you always need to specify which database you want to connect to.

When you set up a new server, you need *something* to connect to before you can run your first `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

That's all the `postgres` database is: a dummy database to use as a connection target for admin commands. There's no data in there, and you're free to drop it and use a different one instead (though whoever inherits your system will probably not thank you for it...).

As gil.fernandes said in his answer, server-wide objects like users are accessible from every database, but aren't stored inside any database in particular.